# When using TailwindCSS, how do I avoid the template from adding a divider to divide-y when rendering a list?

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

Divide-y serves to add dividers 'in between' stacked elements.  When rendering a list with AlpineJS (x-for) and TailwindCSS, however, we find that the template tag is causing the CSS to add a divider there as well, which is an undesired effect.

Is there a Tailwind-way to prevent this?

e.g.

```
<ul role="list" class="divide-y divide-gray-200" x-data="taskModel()">
    <template x-for="task in taskList">
        <li class="py-4 flex">
            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            <div class="ml-3">
                <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900" x-text="task.name"></p>
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500" x-text="task.email"></p>
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500" x-text="task.due"></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>

<script>
    function taskModel() {
        return {
            taskList: [
                {
                    name: 'Calvin Hawkins',
                    email: 'calvin.hawkins@example.com',
                    due: '2021-08-28'
                }
            ]
        };
    }
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty [well documented](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/387) and accounted for issue. As described in the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2#add-hidden-to-any-template-tags-within-space-or-divide-elements All you need to do is add the `hidden` attribute to your template tag.

In your case the code should be:

```html
<ul role="list" class="divide-y divide-gray-200" x-data="taskModel()">
    <!-- Add hidden attribute -->
    <template x-for="task in taskList" hidden>
        <li class="py-4 flex">
            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            <div class="ml-3">
                <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900" x-text="task.name"></p>
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500" x-text="task.email"></p>
                <p class="text-sm text-gray-500" x-text="task.due"></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>

<script>
    function taskModel() {
        return {
            taskList: [
                {
                    name: 'Calvin Hawkins',
                    email: 'calvin.hawkins@example.com',
                    due: '2021-08-28'
                }
            ]
        };
    }
</script>
```